# static class member not recognised but only for new versions of C++ compile

Tags: c++, clang, c++14

The static class member `static_member` not recognised in the following code.

However, it works on older versions of the compiler. The compiler I use is based on `clang`.

```cpp
class my_class {
  public:
    static int static_member;
};

int main() {
  my_class::static_member = 0;
}
```

To reproduce the error, save above file as `c1.cpp` and run:

```sh
VER_TAG=latest # or VER_TAG=3.1.8

docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src emscripten/emsdk::$VER_TAG emcc /src/c1.cpp
```

Leads to error:

> wasm-ld: error: /tmp/emscripten_temp_o3wmmq8k/c1_0.o: undefined symbol: my_class::static_member

However, if I use
`VER_TAG=2.0.22` (earlier release of the compiler), it works fine.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Or is it related to compiler implementation?

Comment: Change it to: `int my_class::static_member = 0;` and move the definition outside main function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [static data member's definition's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static):

> The **declaration inside the class body is not a definition** and may declare the member to be of incomplete type (other than void), including the type in which the member is declared.

So we have to first provide an **out-of class definition** for the static data member as shown below:

```
class my_class {
  public:
    static int static_member;//this is a declaration
};
int my_class::static_member = 0;//this is a definition
int main() {
 std::cout<<my_class::static_member<<std::endl;
}
```

---

From C++17 onwards we can use `inline` keyword so that we'll not need an out-of-class definition for the static data member anymore:

```
class my_class {
  public:
    inline static int static_member = 0;  // this is a definition
};

//nothing needed here

int main() {
  std::cout<<my_class::static_member; // use the static_member here
}
```

Comment: Got my vote for mentioning `inline`. I tend to forget that version :-)

Comment: Great. I will tag @ted-lyngmo as accepted answer only because he answered earlier. Thanks for the extra education by mentioning "out-of class definition" and the new `inline` usage.

Comment: @jason-liam Use of `inline` is a neat solution. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there anything wrong with my code?

Yes, your `static_member` doesn't have a definition.

```
class my_class {
  public:
    static int static_member;  // declaration
};

int my_class::static_member{}; // missing definition

int main() {
  my_class::static_member = 0; // now you can use it here
}
```

Comment: Excellent. So, how was it working before? Is it a new requirement in recent updates of C++?

Comment: @SohailSi I think your older linker had a flaw that didn't detect this missing definition - or perhaps the compiler somehow added a definition by itself for some reason.

Comment: Not sure which one to choose as the chosen answer: Your last comment is great: it explained the "cause" of the problem (and confusion). The other answer gave the "solution" for the problem (`inline`).

Comment: @SohailSi Yes, `inline` is one way to solve it from C++17. Prior to C++17, you had to do it like I showed in my answer (which still works btw).